# How to recurse to find maximum number of tetris tiles that will fit

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

I'm working on a practice problem about tiling a kitchen with Tetris tiles. Basically I have a certain number of tiles in Tetris shapes, and I want to find the maximum number I can fit on a given sized floor.

[Here's the full problem description](https://github.com/instructure/contests/blob/master/2012-mebipenny/contest/kyles-kitchen/description.html)

I already have a lot of useful functions, including calculating all possible placements of a tile on a grid, whether a given tile can be placed at all, etc. [Here's what I have so far](https://github.com/seanhess/mebipenny/blob/master/haskell/2012/KylesKitchen.hs)

I can't figure out how to write the main function though. How should I be recursing through the tiles?

One idea I had was to use [`subsequences`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:subsequences) to get all combinations of tiles, then see whether they all fit or not. Then I just find the largest list that fit. What other (better?) ways are there to do it?

Comment: Well the subsequences method works but my code is too slow :( What would you do? I just pushed my solution.

Comment: AFAIK this kind of problem is generally *hard* (as in computationally hard). So I wouldn't expect *any* solution to work efficiently for big areas.

Comment: Hmm.. They have a reference solution here: https://github.com/instructure/contests/blob/master/2012-mebipenny/contest/kyles-kitchen/solution.rb - and they have test cases. I time out on about half of them.

Comment: It may be. What I meant is that general tessellation problems are hard. Probably the shapes and number of shapes chosen allows a simple algorithm to find an optimal tessellation but with generic shapes you can't do much better than generate & test and the number of tessellations is exponential.

Answer (score 2):

Update:

There is a lot of literature on this kind of problem. Besides "tetris packing problem" you will also find useful results searching for "polyomino packing".

In particular, this article might be useful:

- http://www.mattbusche.org/blog/article/polycube

Original Answer:

One issue I see is that you are not pruning your search enough.

Your main search function is this:

```
maxTiles :: Grid -> [Tile] -> Int
maxTiles g ts =
    let tss = subsequences ts
        gs = map (\ts -> placeAllTiles ts g) tss
        scores = map (uncurry scoreGrid) $ zip tss gs
    in maximum scores
```

You are calling `placeAllTiles` on all subsequences of your tile set.
Suppose your tile set is `A A B B C C D D` and after placing `A A B B` the grid is filled up. `maxTiles` will still call `placeAllTiles` with `A A B B C`, and `A A B B C C` and `A A B B C C D`, and others. You want to find a way to prune the search if you get into this kind of situation.

You should also prune if there is no way to improve the score. In general this means you are going to have to use a search algorithm which keeps track of the current best solution and prunes away search paths which are not going to be fruitful.

Here is a outline of a brute-force algorithm:

1. Each space in the grid can be occupied by either a piece or
   a "blank" space.
2. Keep track of the current grid, the pieces remaining, and the
      best solution so far.
3. If there are no more available spaces in the grid, return
      the best solution so far.
4. If there are no more pieces, return the best solution so far.
5. Pick some available grid square. Consider all possible ways of
      filling that square with a piece or a "blank". For each of those
      possible ways, find the best solution by recursing.